# PHP Error Object of Class Could Not Be Converted to String

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, type-conversion

I am trying to create a PHP file that connects to a mysql database and inserts data into the database. I am getting these errors:

( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class foo_mysqli could not be converted to string in ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: host in C:\wamp\www\final_kk.php on line 21

( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class foo_mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\final_kk.php on line 21

Line 21 is the first line inside of the try. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php

class foo_mysqli extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
}

$db = new foo_mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');

echo 'Success... ' . $db->host_info . "\n";

try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;username=$user;password=$pass", $user, $pass);


            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname,email,username,password,SSN) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$password', '$ssn')";


            // use exec() because no results are returned
            $conn->exec($sql);
            echo "New record created successfully";
            }

        catch(PDOException $e)
            {

            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }

    $db->close();
    ?>
```

Okay....I made some changes based on the comments and my code now looks like this:

```
<?php

class foo_mysqli extends mysqli {
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
}

$db = new foo_mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');

echo 'Success... ' . $db->host_info . "\n";
settype($host, "string"); 
settype($user, "string");   
settype($pass, "string");    
try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db, $user, $pass");


            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname,email,username,password,SSN) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$password', '$ssn')";


            // use exec() because no results are returned
            $conn->exec($sql);
            echo "New record created successfully";
            }

        catch(PDOException $e)
            {

            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }

$db->close();
?>
```

This got rid of one of my errors however I still get

( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class foo_mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\final_kk.php on line 33

please help...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: not your solution, but a hint, remove that `;username=$user;password=$pass` from your pdo constructor, its not needed!

Comment: `$db = new foo_mysqli` …later… `$conn = new PDO("…dbname=$db;…"` — When creating `$conn`, you use the `$db` variable inside a double-quoted string, but the `$db` variable is a `foo_mysqli` object which doesn't have a [__toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `$db` as an instance of a `foo_mysqli()` object in this line:

```
$db = new foo_mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');
```

Later in

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;username=$user;password=$pass", $user, $pass);
```

you're using `$db` as a database name. It's enclosed in a double-quoted string, so PHP will attempt to interpolate it and substitute a string in the PDO connection string. Since `$db` is now an object, it fails.

It's not clear why you're setting up an object that extends MySQLi when you're later using a PDO object anyway.

Additionally, you haven't defined `$host` in the scope where you're setting up your PDO connection, so PHP reports that as undefined.

Since you know what the host and database names are you could just do this:

```
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users;", $user, $pass);
```